# Add a slider in d3.js element

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Here is my code, i am adding a series of rectangle - http://jsfiddle.net/nikunj2512/74qrC/6/

i want to add a slider like a image slider which has left and right arrow buttons for navigation or something similar, so that user can navigate through the rectangle boxes.

I don't know how to achieve this thing.

This is the `d3.js` code which is creating the rectangle boxes:

```
var width = 4000,
height = 200,
margin = 2,
nRect = 20,
rectWidth = (width - (nRect - 1) * margin) / nRect,
svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var data = d3.range(nRect),
posScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data))
    .range([0, width - rectWidth]);

svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
   .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', posScale)
    .attr('width', rectWidth)
    .attr('height', height);
```

Comment: What do you mean by navigate? If you mean in terms of "selecting" something it would be quite easy -- in the click event handler for your buttons you would need to simply move to the respective next element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fun... So, I think I suggested this approach in your other question, but basically I apply a clip path to the rectangles:

```
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
.attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
        .attr("width", clipWidth)
        .attr("height", clipHeight);

var g = svg.append("g");
g.selectAll("rect").data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
        .attr("class", "area").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr('x', xScale)
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
        .attr('height', rectHeight)
        .style('fill', d3.scale.category20());
```

...and then I skew the domain up or down and update the plot using a transition with a delay of 500ms:

```
var update = function(){
    g.selectAll("rect")
        .transition().duration(500)
        .attr('x', xScale);
};

d3.select("#left").on("click", function(){ 
    xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[0] - 1, xScale.domain()[1] - 1]);
    update();
});
```

and voila, a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/74qrC/9/

Now, the trick is to load images in those boxes, but you should be able to do some googling for how to apply images to svg elements and there's plenty of resources out there to help you do that.

Comment: Thank you for Your help.... you are really Awesome..... Please take a look on this implementation of [slider](http://jsfiddle.net/nikunj2512/SqKZv/).....  i am using [Dragdealer JS](http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/)... This is not working in chrome but working in firefox... Can You tell help me out with this?

Comment: To bound the sliders, the trick is to check the boundaries of the domain against how many rects are visible. See update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/74qrC/12/

Comment: The question about dragdealer in FF vs Chrome is a different question, can you accept this one and post a new question?

Comment: thank You........ OK, i had created a new question, please take a look, when You get time.... Here is the link to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878803/d3-js-and-dragdealer-js)

Comment: If possible, can we display something like 1/10 etc ?

Comment: What do you mean by 1/10? Display one of ten of the rects?

Comment: Like it will show through how many rectangles user have navigated like if user had click on right once then count will become 4/10 to 5/10 and so on and if use click on left the count will decrease...

Comment: yeah, you could just use the different variables (width, visible, etc) to determine how many are hidden on each side based on the current state of the domain. So, when you update the domain, you'd also want to update the text of whatever div's you're using to display that info with the new counts.