# D3.js and dragdealer JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am using `dragdealer JS` with `D3.js`. What i am doing is that when You drag the slider made by `dragdealer JS` the elements made by `D3.js` will move like a picture slider.

Here is the code which which i wrote : [code](http://jsfiddle.net/nikunj2512/SqKZv/).

Now there are two problems with this code:

1) This code is working in FireFox but not in Chrome & IE 10?

2) How to configure the slider so that on one slide, only one tile will move into the view and only one will move out?

The number of tiles or rectangles are not fixed. There can be any number of tiles depending on the user.

Code:

```
var width = 4000,
height = 200,
margin = 2,
nRect = 20,
rectWidth = (width - (nRect - 1) * margin) / nRect,
svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width);

var data = d3.range(nRect),
posScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data))
    .range([0, width - rectWidth]);
console.log(rectWidth)
svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('x', posScale)
.attr('width', rectWidth)
.attr('height', height);

function redraw(x) 
{


    svg.transition()        
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + -(x*rectWidth) + ")" );

        console.log(-(x*rectWidth));

}

var step = nRect/2;
new Dragdealer('magnifier',
{
    steps: step,
    snap: true,
    animationCallback: function(x, y)
    { console.log(x*10)
        redraw(x*step);

    }
});
```

i am trying to devise a way so that the value of `steps` will change according to the number of tiles.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few problems that I've fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/SqKZv/1/

1. In Chrome your `svg` element needed the `height` property set
2. In Chrome/IE, it doesn't appear that you can apply the `transform` attribute to your `SVG` element, I'm actually surprised this works in FireFox.  I wrapped all of your `rect` elements in a `g` element and transformed that.

D3 does dragging very well by itself, so you don't need Dragdealer to do this.  In addition to [d3.behavior.drag](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior), you can check out [d3.svg.brush](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls), specifically these examples of snapping to get what you want:

- Brush Snapping http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232537
- Brush Snapping II http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232620

Comment: Langdon Thank you.... In all the examples drag examples the all the elements are visible to the user and over that we are dragging but i trying to achieve something like in the terms of image slider. If You have any idea about that please let me know other than this slider....

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try out the new D3 feature called brush: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls

Here is an example I made using brush to implement a similar feature as you mentioned. 
https://github.com/CSE512-14W/a3-chaoyu-aniket